# c# - SqlConnection InfoMessage triggering only at end of execution

Tags: c#, sql

I am using

```
sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(sqlConnection_InfoMessage);
```

and `ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute a stored procedure.

I am using `RAISERROR("Custom Message", 10 , 1) WITH NOWAIT` in stored procedure to throw message.

I am getting all message thrown by sql server at end of query execution which i want at the time of process.

I could get all the message at real time by setting `sqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;` but this cause the error with severity greater than 10 also be handled by `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler` which i want to be thrown as exception .

Is there any way to get my custom sql infomessage with severity 10 at real time in eventHandler but other as exception?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems like the issue is with `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

In my case I used `ExecuteScalar()` and removed the line

`sqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;`

Which cause the  `RAISERROR("Custom Message", 10 , 1) WITH NOWAIT`  to be caught by eventHandler and other as exceptions at real time.

Comment: ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery did the trick for me, thank you !

Comment: +1 This also worked for me. However, one word of caution: From what I can tell, if your query returns any result sets, then `ExecuteScalar()` ignores everything after the first result set, INCLUDING any further messages. In this case, I had to go back to using `ExecuteNonQuery()` with `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true`.